# How to output lines into one string separated by space (bash)

Tags: string, bash, line

I have this construction in Bash

```
while read line
do
    echo $line | while read  a b c d e f g
    do
        if [ $e != "0" ]; then
        echo -en "|'$a'=;$g;$f;;"
        fi
    done
done < /tmp/res6
```

Which cat this text

```
mem_total_app_1 5034876928  + 384000 = 5035260928       mysqld
mem_total_app_2 2994008064  + 108532736 = 3102540800    /usr/sbin/amavi(91)
mem_total_app_3 648744960  + 103424 = 648848384 redis-server
mem_total_app_4 541454336  + 58354688 = 599809024       php-fpm7.2(26)
```

and output to this

```
|'mem_total_app_1'=;mysqld;5035260928;;
|'mem_total_app_2'=;/usr/sbin/amavi(91);3102540800;;
|'mem_total_app_3'=;redis-server;648848384;;
|'mem_total_app_4'=;php-fpm7.2(26);599809024;;
```

I would like to have the output in one string separated by space. Like this

```
|'mem_total_app_1'=;mysqld;5035260928;; 'mem_total_app_2'=;amavi(91);3102540800;; 'mem_total_app_3'=;redis-server;648848384;; 'mem_total_app_4'=;php-fpm7.2(26);599809024;;
```

Could somebody prompt me, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Try `printf`

The `printf` command provides a method to *print preformatted text* similar to the `printf()` system interface (*C function*). It's meant as `successor for echo` and has far **more features and possibilities**.

```
printf "|"
while read line
do
    echo $line | while read  a b c d e f g
    do
        if [ $e != "0" ]; then
        printf " '$a'=;$g;$f;;"
        fi
    done
done  < /tmp/res6
```

---

Output :-

```
| 'mem_total_app_1'=;mysqld;5035260928;; 'mem_total_app_2'=;/usr/sbin/amavi(91);3102540800;; 'mem_total_app_3'=;redis-server;648848384;; 'mem_total_app_4'=;php-fpm7.2(26);599809024;;
```

Comment: The nested `while` loops are unnecessary, though. Since you don't use `line` for anything, you can simply make the outer `read` split the input into `a b c` etc. That also incidentally fixes the lack of quoting (sheuld be `echo "$line"`).

Answer (score 2):

`tr '\n' ' '` is a nice way, but if you want to avoid having a space at the end, use

```
<input_file paste -sd' '
```

This is handy eg for calculations with `bc`:

```
<one_number_on_line paste -sd+ | bc
```

gives you a sum of all lines (with one number per line).

Answer (score 1):

Simply substitute newline with space:

```
tr '\n' ' ' < input_filename
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply `cat` and `echo`

```
cat input_filename | xargs echo
```

or with `paste`

```
paste -sd " " input_filename
```

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the prettiest way, but you could pipe the entire loop to `tr` like this:

```
{
    while read line
    do
        echo $line | while read  a b c d e f g
        do
            if [ $e != "0" ]; then
            echo -en "|'$a'=;$g;$f;;"
            fi
        done
    done < /tmp/res6
} | tr '\n' ' '
```

(Note spaces around mustache braces.)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN{OFS=";";ORS=";; ";printf "|"}{print "\047"$1"\047",$NF,$(NF-1)}' file
```

The script sets the output delimiter `OFS` and `ORS` such that it can print the content using `;`. Note that `\047` is the single quote character.